# Loop that won't stop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, integer

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to write a loop to find the LARGEST integer n so n^3 < 12,000. I know something is wrong, but I don't know what. Please help!

Here's my code:

```
working = True

n = 12000

while working:
    n = n - 1
    if ((n * n * n) < 12000) and not working:
        print(n)
```

Comment: `while True:  print("tears")`

Comment: You could use the power operator and do `n ** 3` instead of `n * n * n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you found the answer, you need to turn the `working` flag to `False`, like this

```
while working:
    n = n - 1
    if ((n * n * n) < 12000):   # You don't need the  `and not working:` check
        print(n)
        working = False
```

On a side note, in Python, you can find the powers of numbers like this

```
n ** 3 == n * n * n
```

And it turns out that, the answer to your actual question is `22` :)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in this code which sets the value of `working` to `False`, so `working` is always `True`, so the loop will never exit.

Comment: Right. `not working` evaluates to the negation of `working`, but does not mutate the value of that variable.

Comment: @user3105664 to *assign* to `working` you must say `working = X`.  Python is unlike C in that you cannot perform assignment in conditionals.  On the whole, that's a Good Thing.

Comment: @NickT to perform assignment in C you do generally still have to use `=` though `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
while working:
```

Says that you will continue to loop as long as `working` is `True`.  You never set `working` to `False` inside the loop, so it will loop forever.

You probably want something like this:

```
while working:
    n = n - 1
    if ((n * n * n) < 12000):
        working = False
        print(n)
```